# Deploy Windows To Go on external drive using Network boot, WDS or SCCM and WinPE

Tags: boot, wds, winpe, sccm

We are doing a project for a IT school, each student have an external drive (WD My Passport enterprise) and we are trying to deploy Windows To Go on these drives.

Each student should be able to flash his drive just by connecting it to a school computer and then power the computer on and do a network boot and use Windows Deployment Service or SCCM to deploy the Windows To Go on the external drive.

We have already a Windows server 2012 running with WDS and another with SCCM for tests.

When we try to deploy on the external drive (disk no 1 selected in our task sequence) we have an error in WinPE it says in brief : Can not format disk 1 because it is not an internal fixed drive.

Is there a workaround ?

Here is the error in LitetouchPE:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p33xqwz6q8axc6p/IMG_20150120_132201.jpg?dl=0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed this by adding a .bat diskpart format script in the task sequence and removing the default format script.